# Create thunmbnail from urls?

Tags: php, url, external, thumbnails

i am trying to use this function to create thumbnails from extenals urls from amazon s3.

```
function resizeImage($originalImage,$toWidth,$toHeight){

    // Get the original geometry and calculate scales
    list($width, $height) = file_get_contents($originalImage);
    $xscale=$width/$toWidth;
    $yscale=$height/$toHeight;

    // Recalculate new size with default ratio
    if ($yscale>$xscale){
        $new_width = round($width * (1/$yscale));
        $new_height = round($height * (1/$yscale));
    }
    else {
        $new_width = round($width * (1/$xscale));
        $new_height = round($height * (1/$xscale));
    }

    // Resize the original image
    $imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $imageTmp     = imagecreatefromjpeg ($originalImage);
    imagecopyresampled($imageResized, $imageTmp, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

    return $imageResized;
}
```

The problem i had is it only seems to work with relative urls i get the following errors.

```
Warning: Division by zero in /home/isd/public_html/swfupload/resize.php on line 15

Warning: Division by zero in /home/isd/public_html/swfupload/resize.php on line 16

Warning: imagecreatetruecolor() [function.imagecreatetruecolor]: Invalid image dimensions in /home/isd/public_html/swfupload/resize.php on line 20

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(Chrysanthemum.jpg) [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/isd/public_html/swfupload/resize.php on line 21

Warning: imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in /home/isd/public_html/swfupload/resize.php on line 22

Warning: Division by zero in /home/isd/public_html/swfupload/resize.php on line 15

Warning: Division by zero in /home/isd/public_html/swfupload/resize.php on line 16

Warning: imagecreatetruecolor() [function.imagecreatetruecolor]: Invalid image dimensions in /home/isd/public_html/swfupload/resize.php on line 20

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(Desert.jpg) [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/isd/public_html/swfupload/resize.php on line 21

Warning: imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in /home/isd/public_html/swfupload/resize.php on line 22

Warning: file_get_contents(http://isdprogress.s3.amazonaws.com/HQ preview.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported in /home/isd/public_html/swfupload/resize.php on line 5
```

Does anyone now a good way or function i can use that works to resize images to thunmbnails from external urls???

Thanks

Comment: What is line 15 in resize.php??

Answer (score 2):

file_get_contents does not return the width nor the height of an image resource.

It returns the content of a file into a string: http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Use imagesx and imagesy instead:

http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php

http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesy.php

**Add:**

I don't know your process, but I think you just retrieve the image as a string with file_get_contents, which is not a valid image resource.

So, you have to convert this data into an image resource. Use imagecreatefromstring function: http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

Disclaimer: I don't see your full code, so it's just a guess that you don't have an image resource :)

Comment: hi sorry should have mention i was using getimagesize() instead of file_get_contents but still had errors

Comment: check out the additional info

Comment: hi thanks for the reply my code is pretty basic really i am using undesigneds s3 class, and i am pulling some images from my bucket.

Comment: //instantiate the class
$s3 = new S3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);

// Get the contents of our bucket
$bucket_contents = $s3->getBucket($S3_BUCKET);

foreach ($bucket_contents as $file){

    $fname = $file['name'];
    $furl = "http://{$S3_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/".$fname;
    echo "<img src=\"$furl\" alt=\"amazon image\" align=\"left\" width=\"96\" height=\"96\" />";
 
}

Comment: as you can see i am just forcing to resize them to 96 x 96 but i am just looking for a better way to do this as my images look crushed and distorted

Comment: You should cut your image to 96x96. I would do it like this: 1. resize to the minimum possible size (nor the width and nor the height is lower than 96, but the height or the width is 96px). 2. cut the 96x96 piece from the image and save it. This is an easy way to resize a custom ratio image with the smallest loss. If you are interested in, i can show you a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok

Finally got it working for this great solution here http://joedesigns.com/v22/?page=scripts_widgets&id=67

Work a treat ;)